# XML Linq return nothing office add-ins

Tags: c#, xml

I have a question. I am trying to read a remote XML file.
everything works fine except the Linq query it always return nothing.

I used this code:

```
XDocument doc = ConnectToXML(url);
    List<LongProfile> result = doc.Descendants("Details").Select(x => new LongProfile
                     {
                         Firstname = x.Attribute("Textbox10").Value,
                         Lastname = x.Attribute("Textbox8").Value,
                         TeamLeader = x.Attribute("Textbox5").Value,
                         Status = x.Attribute("Textbox26").Value,
                         Date = x.Attribute("Textbox14").Value
                     }).ToList();

    if (result.Count == 0) MessageBox.Show("null");
```

and it always show null.

this is a part of the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<Report xmlns="ProfilpflegeStatus" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="ProfilpflegeStatus" xsi:schemaLocation="ProfilpflegeStatus http://bitreporting/ReportServer?%2FSkillscout%2FProfilpflegeStatus&rs%3AFormat=XML&rc%3ASchema=True">


-<Tablix1>


-<Details_Collection>

<Details Textbox15="Klaus Baumgärtner" Textbox5="Marketing Kommunikation" Textbox3="Mannheim" Textbox26="Nein" Textbox10="Mona" Textbox8="Aalfeld"/>

<Details Textbox15="Marc Schmitt" Textbox5="Marc Schmitt" Textbox3="Mannheim" Textbox26="Nein" Textbox10="Frank" Textbox8="Abegg" Textbox14="2013-03-11T19:18:22.513" Textbox12="Service Management"/>

<Details Textbox15="Marc Schmitt" Textbox5="Marc Schmitt" Textbox3="Mannheim" Textbox26="Ja" Textbox10="Frank" Textbox8="Abegg" Textbox14="2016-09-08T23:21:45" Textbox12="Standard" Textbox24="2016-09-08T23:21:45"/>

<Details Textbox15="Marc Schmitt" Textbox5="Marc Schmitt" Textbox3="Mannheim" Textbox26="Nein" Textbox10="Frank" Textbox8="Abegg" Textbox14="2012-11-29T01:51:13.16" Textbox12="Testing"/>

<Details Textbox15="Marc Schmitt" Textbox5="Marc Schmitt" Textbox3="Mannheim" Textbox26="Nein" Textbox10="Frank" Textbox8="Abegg" Textbox14="2013-05-14T22:50:08.53" Textbox12="Testmanagement"/>
```

I am not that expert with XML. so please if you can help me to solve this problem. and provide me with some explaination. it would be great.

thank you very much.

Comment: I would guess that `ConnectToXM(url)` isn't actually returning an XDocument that represents what you've posted.  What you posted doesn't have a root element, and XDocument can't even load XML without a root element

Comment: I just check the doc that returns from this method, which is exactly the same as the XML file. 

all works find. only when I want to read

when I write : MessageBox.Show(doc + ""); 
it shows all the XML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it to work
1) You can't have the characters '&', 'ä' in the xml file.
2) You need a namespace for the linq to work
3) Don't use property 'Value' when some of the element don't have all the attributes.  It give a null error.  Instead cast like I did below.

Here is updated xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report xmlns="ProfilpflegeStatus" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="ProfilpflegeStatus" xsi:schemaLocation="ProfilpflegeStatus http://bitreporting/ReportServer?%2FSkillscout%2FProfilpflegeStatusU+0026%3AFormat=XMLU+0026%3ASchema=True">
  <Tablix1>
    <Details_Collection>
      <Details Textbox15="Klaus Baumgärtner" Textbox5="Marketing Kommunikation" Textbox3="Mannheim" Textbox26="Nein" Textbox10="Mona" Textbox8="Aalfeld"/>
      <Details Textbox15="Marc Schmitt" Textbox5="Marc Schmitt" Textbox3="Mannheim" Textbox26="Nein" Textbox10="Frank" Textbox8="Abegg" Textbox14="2013-03-11T19:18:22.513" Textbox12="Service Management"/>
      <Details Textbox15="Marc Schmitt" Textbox5="Marc Schmitt" Textbox3="Mannheim" Textbox26="Ja" Textbox10="Frank" Textbox8="Abegg" Textbox14="2016-09-08T23:21:45" Textbox12="Standard" Textbox24="2016-09-08T23:21:45"/>
      <Details Textbox15="Marc Schmitt" Textbox5="Marc Schmitt" Textbox3="Mannheim" Textbox26="Nein" Textbox10="Frank" Textbox8="Abegg" Textbox14="2012-11-29T01:51:13.16" Textbox12="Testing"/>
      <Details Textbox15="Marc Schmitt" Textbox5="Marc Schmitt" Textbox3="Mannheim" Textbox26="Nein" Textbox10="Frank" Textbox8="Abegg" Textbox14="2013-05-14T22:50:08.53" Textbox12="Testmanagement"/>
    </Details_Collection>
  </Tablix1>
</Report>







using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement report = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;
            XNamespace ns = report.GetDefaultNamespace();

            List<LongProfile> result = doc.Descendants(ns + "Details").Select(x => new LongProfile() {
                Firstname = (string)x.Attribute("Textbox10"),
                Lastname = (string)x.Attribute("Textbox8"),
                TeamLeader = (string)x.Attribute("Textbox5"),
                Status = (string)x.Attribute("Textbox26"),
                Date = x.Attribute("Textbox14") == null ? new DateTime() :(DateTime)x.Attribute("Textbox14")
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class LongProfile
    {
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string TeamLeader { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime  Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works man, thank you very much for the solution and for the explaination. just to mention something: 
there is no problem I guess with the letter "ä" because it recognized in the German keyboard. 

but the name space and the attribute was totally right. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

A qualified name in XML is made up of a namespace and a local name. You've queried with the local name `Details` but haven't taken account of the namespace.

The namespace is the default (as there is no 'prefix' on the name, and the default namespace is defined by the `xmlns="..."` attribute on an element or any parent element.  In this case, this is in the root `Report` element - the namespace is `ProfilpflegeStatus`.

You can use this in your query like this:

```
XNamespace ns = "ProfilpflegeStatus";
var details = doc.Descendants(ns + "Details");
```

Once you have this working, I'd not that some of the attributes you're selecting don't exist on all `Details` elements. You can handle this by making us of the explicit conversions available which will handle the case where the `XAttribute` returned is `null`.  For example:

```
Firstname = (string)x.Attribute("Textbox10")
```

Comment: you are right, thanks. but unfortunately I cannot make two answers as correct. but thank you